# O shaped Uvtuvo Washing Cup

Tags: halacha, netilat-yadayim-washing

Is the O shaped Uvtuvo Washing Cup kosher for Netilat Yadayim according to all opinions? If not, what are the sources and issues so one can make an informed decision? Thanks!

[Uvtuvo cup](https://www.uvtuvo.com/products/o-washing-cup-vase-modern-judaica-uvtuvo)

Comment: If you don't mind, I'd rather stick with the good old two-handled washing cups made of plastic that you can pick up from a Judaica joint for $3 or so... Not only is it much cheaper but it's also better according to all opinions.

Comment: Welcome to Mi Yodeya! Please take a look at our [tour] where you can find some useful information about the site. What makes you think that there are potential problems with washing cups that you ask this?

Comment: It would be great if your question was self-standing, and wouldn't require the use of Google to see what cup you are speaking about. Would you mind adding an image by [edit]ing your question?

Answer (score 2):

If you have a "cup" that has a hole in it that leaks water, you may only pour out water to wash your hands from that hole [if its possible to pour from there]. Any part of the cup above the hole, is not considered a kosher utensil for washing. [See Shulchan Aruch A"H 159/2]

In your case, when the cup is standing on it's base, the water will only go up to a certain point. Anything above  that point would not be considered a kli - utensil. Therefore, if the water you are washing your hands with, is coming above the top, it would not be an acceptable washing. I would think it is difficult to be careful about this, and not advisable to use for washing on a regular basis.